# Run an async function from a sync function... without knowing whether there is already a running event loop?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

So it is a common question for someone first coming to python's async to ask, "how do I run an async function from a sync function?" Hopefully if you're here you already know that the answer to that question is `asyncio.run()`.

But this is *not* really the answer. Because suppose I want to write an ad hoc set of scripts in which, in a few places within it, I want to call a few coroutines. `asyncio.run` "should ideally only be called once" and "cannot be called when another asyncio event loop is running in the same thread." In general you cannot have two event loops running in the same thread.

In the ad hoc scenario I imagine I would like an idiom which is "block execution of this non-async function, and its event loop if there is one, until this coroutine finishes". It must tolerate being run whether an event loop exists or not and whether it is running or not. If there is no running event loop this easy. If there is, it should have the same effect as creating another event loop, calling `run_until_complete` on that, then resuming execution of the calling function (which, eventually, will pass control back to the original loop, though since it's not async, that might not be for a while.)

For example:

```py
async def coro1():
  pass

def function1():
  better_asyncio_run(coro1())

def function2():
  function1()
  better_asyncio_run(coro1())

async def coro2():
  function2()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  better_asyncio_run(coro2())
```

One might be tempted to answer, "rewrite your code to all be async" which is I guess giving in to the nightmare. It surely shouldn't be necessary for the rapid prototyping we love python for. If there is some fundamental reason why it can't work, I haven't spotted it and would love to know what it is.

Comment: Can you post a code example?

Comment: The trouble with your scenario is that async functions contain await expressions, which yield control back to the event loop.  To do that, they must know how to suspend their own execution, and resume from that known point when the event loop allows them to do so.  Sync functions do not have this capability, so they can't be suspended and resumed in this way.  Sync functions nest in a call stack, unwinding the stack when they return.  Coroutines do not nest but run concurrently by cooperating with an event loop.  You may consider this a nightmare but others regard it as extremely useful.

Comment: `asyncio.run` does not yield control to the event loop and nor should the construct I am talking about. Is there some reason I'm missing why it *must*?

Comment: Asyncio.run() does not itself yield back to the event loop, but the coroutine that is its argument can.  True, coroutines do not *have* to contain await expressions but they almost always do.  So there really cannot be a *general* solution along the lines you are describing, because of the necessity of allowing a coroutine to execute its await expressions.  In your example you basically show a standard sync-type program where tasks are not cooperatively multitasking.  If you need more than one event loop, threads often are the answer.

Comment: Please do assume that I know what is involved in async programming. Is there something ill-defined or contradictory about the behaviour I specified in the question? The inner coroutine yielding back to the event loop does not, that I see, prevent the behaviour. Threading is a fine answer *if there is an idiomatic way to do this with threading*.